# Using substitute in multiple function calls

Tags: r, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

```r
foo <- function(arg) {
  substitute(arg)
}

foo1 <- function(parm) {
  foo(param)
}
foo1(2 + 2)
```

output is:

```
param
```

How can I use substitute inside `foo` such that the output will be the expression `2 + 2`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the rlang approach:

```
foo <- function(...) {
  x <- rlang::enexprs(...)
  x[[1]]
}
foo(2 + 2)
```

Result is:

```
2 + 2
```

Comment: The input to `foo1` could be any expression, not limited to a string. And it is not supposed to evaluate either. So outputting 4 is not desired.

Comment: You are missing the point completely. Your answer doesn't address non-standard evaluation at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo1 <- function(parm) {
  p <- substitute(parm)
  do.call(foo, list(p))
}
foo1(2 + 2)
#2 + 2
```

Comment: I am aware of that solution. However, is there a way to not use `substitute` inside `foo1`?

Comment: @code_life Not easily. Can we make any assumptions regarding the call stack?